# Link between Yamabe invariant and Yamabe equation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, conformal-geometry

I am trying to understand the solution to the Yamabe problem as presented by Lee and Parker. It seems to me that the constant $\lambda$ which appears in the Yamabe equation $$\square\varphi = \lambda \varphi^{p-1}$$ and the Yamabe invariant $\lambda = \inf_\varphi Q_g(\varphi)$ where $Q_g$ is the functional $$Q_{g}(\varphi) = \frac{\int_{M} \left(a|\nabla \varphi|^{2}+S \varphi^{2}\right) d V_{g}}{\|\varphi\|_{p}^{2}} = \frac{E(\varphi)}{\|\varphi\|_{p}^{2}}$$ are in fact the same thing, that is to say if $\varphi$ is an absolute minimum for the functional $Q_g$ then $\varphi$ is a solution to the Yamabe equation with $\lambda$ as the coefficient of $\varphi^{p-1}$. It seems to me that this is proved explicitely by Aubin in his book "Some nonlinear problems in Riemannian geometry".

However, an explicit calculation of the Euler-Lagrange equation for $Q_g$ (which is shown on page 39 of [this paper](https://www.kfki.hu/~iracz/sgimp/cikkek/YamabeProblem.pdf)  by Lee and Parker and which can be easily done explicitly)

*Lee, John M.; Parker, Thomas H.*, [**The Yamabe problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1987-15514-5), Bull. Am. Math. Soc., New Ser. 17, 37-91 (1987). [ZBL0633.53062](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0633.53062).

shows that the Euler equation is
$$
a \Delta \varphi+S \varphi-\|\varphi\|_{p}^{-p} E(\varphi) \varphi^{p-1}=0
$$
that is to say the Yamabe equation with
$$
\lambda = \frac{E(\varphi)}{\|\varphi\|_{p}^{p}}.
$$
For the Yamabe invariant to be the same constant which appears in the Yamabe equation, the exponent at the denominator should be 2 and not $p$.
I am therefore a bit confused: is the Yamabe invariant the same constant in the Yamabe equation in presence of a solution $\varphi$? If yes, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that $Q_g(\varphi)$ is invariant under rescaling of $\varphi$ by a constant, but the first version you give of the Yamabe equation is not invariant under this rescaling unless you assume $\lambda$ rescales, too. So it is probably correct only, if you normalize $\varphi$ somehow ($\|\varphi\|_p = 1$ works).

Comment: In general a good sanity check when writing equations and estimates is to check that everything rescales correctly when you rescale either the function or metric.